# Playing audio in background (Windows 8)

Tags: javascript, windows, html, windows-8

In my app, there is an *audio* tag, playing a MP3 file. When I minimize the app, the audio stops. So, I want to know how to keep it playing.

PD: I use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx) post on the win8 developer blog.  It discusses (among other things) the background audio support in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

As described in this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452730.aspx

You can add the msAudioCategory attribute to your <audio> tag for more functionality. 
For example:

```
<audio msAudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" controls="controls"> 
<source src="song.mp3"/> 
</audio>
```

Comment: Hey I did this way but its not working for me.
I am setting msAudioCategory to BackgroundCapableMedia.When my app goes in background music is not heard.I am getting soundlevel muted event each time.I also registered for MediaTransport protocols still No result.Can anyone suggest a better step by step guide or an sample app.since windows haven't provided sample for the Backgroind capabel media sample